# Doubt on why magnetic flux density is solenoidal

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

The $\mathbf{H}$ field can be derived from the potential $\psi$:

$$\mathbf{H}=\dfrac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int_{V'} \rho  \dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} dV' + \dfrac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \oint_{S'} \sigma \dfrac{ \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} dS'=\mathbf{H}^{V}+\mathbf{H}^{S}$$

where $\rho=-\nabla \cdot \mathbf{M}$ and $\sigma=\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{n}$

$\mathbf{H}^V$ is defined and continuous throughout space. $\mathbf{H}^S$ is defined and continuous everywhere except at boundary $S'$. At the boundary, $\mathbf{H}^S$ is undefined and has a discontinuity of $\mu_0\ \sigma (\hat{n})$. Consequently at the boundary, $\mathbf{H}$ is undefined and has a discontinuity of  $\mu_0\ \sigma (\hat{n})$. Consequently at the boundary, $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{H} + \mu_0 \mathbf{M}$ is undefined and has a discontinuity of  $\mu_0\ \sigma (\hat{n})+\mu_0\mathbf{M}$.

How does it make sense to talk about the divergence at a point where the field is undefined? I know that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}=0$ everywhere except boundary $S'$.

Comment: There are no discontinuities in B-field. div B=0 everywhere. H-field can be discontinuous and have non-zero divergence.

Comment: Then can you please show how $\mu_0\ \sigma (\hat{n})+\mu_0\mathbf{M}=0$

Comment: Because $\nabla \cdot \vec{H} = -\mu_0 \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$

Comment: But can you please show how $\nabla \cdot \vec{H}=\mu_0 \nabla \cdot \sigma (\hat{n})$?

Comment: I do not see how to prove $\mu_0\ \sigma (\hat{n})+\mu_0\mathbf{M}=0$

Comment: $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ if there are no monopoles. $\vec{B} = H + \mu_0 \vec{M}$. Therefore $\nabla \cdot \vec{H} = -\mu_0 \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$.

Comment: But $\vec{H}$ is discontinuous and not defined at the boundary$S'$ (as posted in my question). So the equation $\nabla \cdot \vec{H} = -\mu_0 \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$ is true at all points except at the boundary $S'$. Am I correct?

Comment: Once I see why $\nabla \cdot \vec{H} = -\mu_0 \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$ holds true at boundary points, I can very easily reach $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ at points in the boundary.